# Change Label Font Size Dynamically Not Updating On Screen

Tags: c#

Am trying to change a label font size depending on screen resolution. Have tried when the form is loading, shown and also in the form constructor, but on screen the font size is the same as design time.

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
if (resolution.Width == 1024 && resolution.Height == 768)
{
   this.labelEnterRegistration.Font = new Font(this.labelEnterRegistration.Font.FontFamily, 40f);
}
```

I've added a double click event to the label to check the font size, and it says it's 40 in a message box (`MessageBox.Show(this.labelEnterRegistration.Font.ToString());`), so why doesn't the form display reflect this?

I have tried the label `Invalidate()`but that didn't work either.

Comment: try lblName.Font = new Font("Arial", mainForm.lblName.Font.Size);

Comment: Thanks, but won't that set the size to the same size it already is? I need to keep the same font but just change its size

Comment: woow  @rodkort you can easily change that .Font.Size to your desired value :)

Comment: I do that already :). In design its 50, in code I change to 40, but is still displaying the label at 50! As if the form isn't refreshing itself

Comment: 50 / 40 == 125%.  Exactly the value that matches a video DPI setting.  So you surely did get the font size to 40 points but then it got rescaled by 125%, so it looks like 50 points again.  Wow, that was a very unlucky choice :)  Although probably not an accident, DPI scaling forever stumps Winforms programmers.  You simply should have passed 40 / 1.25 = 32f.  But don't ever do that because it won't be correct on another machine with a different DPI setting.  Simply make sure your design scales properly so you don't need this hack at all.

Answer (score -1):

Have fixed it. As it was done before it was setting the fonts emSize, I did the following so it changes the pixel size:

```
FontStyle style = this.labelEnterRegistration.Font.Style;
this.labelEnterRegistration.Font = new Font(this.labelEnterRegistration.Font.FontFamily, 40f, style, GraphicsUnit.Pixe
```

And now keeps the same font style as well!!

Thanks for the comments @HEPİMİZYARBAYMEHMETALKANIZ, made me think about it some more.